# Why is google.com not showing doodles anymore?

Tags: google-search, google-doodle

i have noticed tha my google.com page is not showing doodles anymore. Thinking better i've not been seeing doodles for a while, i guess since they introduced the new page layout. This is what i always see.

[image: google]

Is there a way to bring doodles back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google.com is not only the US version of Google but also the International version of Google. As Google Doodles are country specific I would hazard a guess that they have probably decided to exclude Google Doodles from their international search page. Perhaps what is celebrated in one country is offensive to another country (you never know...).

You will have to visit another countries Google Page.
Try:
https://www.google.nl/

Comment: but why google.com is not showing them?

Comment: Yes right even goggle.it wasn't showing this.

Answer (score 1):

They actually are. If you take at [this page](http://www.google.com/doodles/finder/2013/All%20doodles), you will see that the last one is from the 20th of November—two days ago. Is just that some are global and other are localised.